# Is it possible to have an On-chain Set data structure?

Tags: plutus, plutustx

As the title of the question says, is it possible for me to use a `Set` data structure for the `Datum` and/or `Redeemer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any type that works with `PlutusTx.unstableMakeIsData` (or its equivalent) should work, since `Datum` & `Redeemer` are wrappers for `BuiltInData` which is a "wrapper" for `Data`.

EDIT:

I tried the following example:

```
data MySampleType = Dummy (Set Bool) deriving (Show)

instance PlutusTx.FromData (Set Bool)
instance PlutusTx.UnsafeFromData (Set Bool)
instance PlutusTx.ToData (Set Bool)
PlutusTx.unstableMakeIsData ''MySampleType
```

but got the following error messages:

```
GHC Core to PLC plugin: E042:Error: Unsupported feature: Int: use Integer instead
Context: Compiling type: Data.Set.Internal.Size
Context: Compiling data constructor type: Data.Set.Internal.Bin
Context: Compiling type: Data.Set.Internal.Set GHC.Types.Bool
Context: Compiling data constructor type: SampleStateMachine.Dummy
Context: Compiling type: SampleStateMachine.MySampleType
Context: Compiling type: SampleStateMachine.MySampleType
                         -> Plutus.V1.Ledger.Contexts.ScriptContext
                         -> GHC.Types.Bool
Context: Compiling type: Model.Bid.OrderBid
                         -> SampleStateMachine.MySampleType
                         -> Plutus.V1.Ledger.Contexts.ScriptContext
                         -> GHC.Types.Bool
Context: Compiling type: Model.Order.Order
                         -> Model.Bid.OrderBid
                         -> SampleStateMachine.MySampleType
                         -> Plutus.V1.Ledger.Contexts.ScriptContext
                         -> GHC.Types.Bool
Context: Compiling definition of: SampleStateMachine.mkValidator
Context: Compiling expr: SampleStateMachine.mkValidator
Context: Compiling expr at "sample-0.1.0.0-inplace:SampleStateMachine:(206,9)-(206,48)"
```

Which, to the best of my understanding, means that it's not a valid On-Chain code.

Fazit: It's currently not possible. But you could create an issue [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/issues) and request the feature :)